# UIImage release error - *** -[UIImage release]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

I have come up with an error "*** -[UIImage release]: message sent to deallocated instance". Here is what I am doing.

```
void imageFromPicture(AVPicture *pict, int width, int height)
{
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
CFDataRef data = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, pict->data[0], pict->linesize[0]*height,kCFAllocatorNull);
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate( width, 
                            height, 
                            8, 
                            24, 
                            pict->linesize[0], 
                            colorSpace, 
                            bitmapInfo, 
                            provider, 
                            NULL, 
                            NO, 
                            kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CFRelease(data);

[ref_to_self display: image];
[image release];
}

- (void) display:(UIImage*)image
{
self.ImageView.image = image;
}
```

Now, the function imageFromPicture is being called continuously in an infinite loop, until some break condition. This is used to display a continuous sequence of images. This code works properly, but after all my images are displayed and the control returns back to the Operating System I get this error.

Can somebody please tell me what wrong am I doing. I do not have much idea on objective C memory management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
```

returns an autoreleased object, so this line

```
[image release];
```

is unnecessary and invalid.

Comment: Ok, if I do as you say it works properly on the iOS simulator, but when I put my application on the device, the app crashes in the middle, saying memory level warning = 1. This is why I added the line [image release] in my code.

Comment: Are you doing this several times in a loop? Use `NSAutoreleasePool` to relieve some memory pressure.

Comment: Ok I will try that, meanwhile can you please point me to some sample code snippet or document which I can refer to use NSAutoreleasePool, I dont know much about objective C. Thanks..

Comment: [Here's info about autorelease pools](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000047-CJBFBEDI); I actually recommend reading that whole guide, it has some very useful and important information.